# How to fix this error thrown on process exit when using Tibco?

Tags: c#, tibco-rv

When using Tibco, what is the cause of this error?

```
2014-06-27 07:58:39.8230|ERROR|Boot.Processes.ServiceRunner|Ctrl-C handler error.|
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SetEvent(SafeWaitHandle handle)
   at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set()
   at ServiceProxyHelper.SetStateStopped(IServiceProxy serviceProxy) in Container\ServiceProxyHelper.cs:line 387
   at ServiceProxyHelper.ShellStop() in Container\ServiceProxyHelper.cs:line 200
   at ServiceProxy.ShellStop() in Container\ServiceProxy.cs:line 193
   at Boot.Processes.ServiceRunner.ConsoleCancelKeyPress(Object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) in Boot\Processes\ServiceRunner.cs:line 218
^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by calling Tibco's `Environment.Open()` without calling a matching Tibco `Environment.Close()`. Until the reference count reaches 0, Tibco is not actually disposed of properly.

To fix this issue in C#, ensure that there is a `.Dispose()` method on every single class that calls Tibco's `Environment.Open()`, and this `.Dispose()` call calls Tibco's `Environment.Close()`.